# How do I count all cells in a column that have emoji?

Tags: google-sheets, emoji, formulas

I have a problem with emoji in my production database. Since it's in production, all I get out of it is an auto-geneated excel spreadsheet (`.xls`) every so often with tens of thousands of rows. I use **Google Sheets** to parse this so I can easily share the results.

**What formula can I use to get a count of all cells in column *n* that contain emoji?**

For instance:

```
Data
+----+-----------------+
| ID | Name            |
+----+-----------------+
| 1  | Chad            |
+----+-----------------+
| 2  | ✨Darla✨         |
+----+-----------------+
| 3  | John Smith      |
+----+-----------------+
| 4  | Austin ⚠️ Powers |
+----+-----------------+
| 5  | Missus         |
+----+-----------------+

Totals
+----------------------------------+---+
| People named Chad                | 1 |
+----------------------------------+---+
| People with emoji in their names | 3 |
+----------------------------------+---+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit by Ben C. R. Leggiero:

```
=COUNTA(FILTER(A2:A6;REGEXMATCH(A2:A6;"[^\x{0}-\x{F7}]")))
```

Comment: Won't that match numbers, commas, periods, and the like?

Comment: yes, it will. This must be part of Regex: [^A-Za-z.,0-9 ]

Comment: Alright, change your regex to something more general like `[^\x{0}-\x{F7}]` and I'll accept this answer

Comment: @daniel that's fine; the real purpose is that we have ancient systems that only handle ASCII interacting with user input from iPads.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I'll compare these three for performance and get back to y'all.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot extract emojis with regular formula because Google Spreadsheet uses the light-weight re2 regex engine, which lacks [many features](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax), including those necessary to find emojis.

What you need to do is creating a custom formula. Select **Tools** menu, then **Script editor...**. In the script editor, add the following:

```
function find_emoji(s) {
  var re = /[\u1F60-\u1F64]|[\u2702-\u27B0]|[\u1F68-\u1F6C]|[\u1F30-\u1F70]|[\u2600-\u26ff]|[\uD83C-\uDBFF\uDC00-\uDFFF]+/i;
  if (s instanceof Array) {
    return s.map(function(el){return el.toString().match(re);});
  } else {
    return s.toString().match(re);
  }
}
```

Save the script. Go back to your spreadsheet, then test your formula `=find_emoji(A1)`

My test yields the following:

```
| Missus         |    |
| Austin ⚠️ Powers | ⚠   |
| ✨Darla✨        | ✨   |
| joke         |  |
```

And, to count entries that don't have emojis, you can use this formula:

```
=countif( arrayformula(isblank( find_emoji(filter(F2:F,not(isblank(F2:F)))))), FALSE)
```

**EDIT**

I was wrong. You can use regular formula to extract emoji. The regex syntax is `[\x{1F300}-\x{1F64F}]|[\x{2702}-\x{27B0}]|[\x{1F68}-\x{1F6C}]|[\x{1F30}-\x{1F70}]|[\x{2600}-\x{26ff}]|[\x{D83C}-\x{DBFF}\x{DC00}-\x{DFFF}]`

Comment: Why do you use the `[ab-yz]|[12-89]` pattern instead of the `[ab-yz12-89]` one?

Comment: Also, I see a lot of operations going on here. How does the performance of this match up to the other answers? The spreadsheet I'm checking has tens of thousands of rows.

Comment: That will depend on what exactly you need. If you just need an approximate count and don't mind false positives with foreign names, then the simpler regex will work. If you specifically want to count emoji only, but you want performance, then you need to change the custom formula to something more specific so that you can just use something like `=count_not_emoji(A3:A)`

Comment: Answer updated. Regular formula can do this. No need for custom formula.

Comment: I love how thorough your answer is! I'll compare these three for performance and get back to y'all.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
=arrayformula(countif(REGEXMATCH(A2:A6,"[^a-zA-Z\d\s:]"),true))
```

Comment: Thanks for the simple answer! I'll compare these three for performance and get back to y'all.